# $XAX^{-1} = B$, how do you solve for $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$X$, $B$ and $C$ are $ 3\times3$ matrices.
If you have an equation like:
$XAX^{-1}= B$
how do you solve for $X$ keeping the matrix notation?
To be more specific, I don’t know how or even if it’s possible, to leave X alone on either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

$$XAX^{-1}= B \iff XA= BX$$

it’s a system of 9 equations in 9 unknowns

Comment: Yes, I realize that. Sorry for being unclear, but I was asking if there’s any “trick” to leave X on one side only.

Comment: No in general it’s not possible, you have 9 unknowns and thus you need 9 equation  to solve.

Comment: Great, that’s what my primitive math told me, but I wanted a confirmation.Thanks!

Comment: This is a useful approach. Do observe that some solutions $X$ of $XA=BX$ will not be invertible, in which case you cannot go back from $XA=BX$ to $XAX^{-1}=B$. Also, the space of solutions (when non-trivial) may have a higher dimension. For example, if $X$ is a solution, then so are $XA,XA^2,\ldots$. And any linear combination thereof.